# Loop through a list with a condition r

Tags: r, list, dataframe

A dataframe `DF` and a list `mappingList` are given below.

```
DF <- data.frame(
           "colors number 3 former" = c("r","r","?","l","?","r","?","?","r","?"),
           "music number 3 latter" = c("r","l","r","l","r","r","l","l","r","l"),
           "genres number 3 latter" = c("l","r","?","l","?","r","?","l","l","r"),
           "genres number 12 former" = c("r","r","?","l","l","r","l","?","r","?"),
           "music number 12 latter" = c("r","l","?","l","?","r","l","l","r","?"),
           "fabric number 12 latter" = c("l","r","?","l","r","r","r","l","l","r"),
           "colors number 12 latter" = c("r","r","?","r","?","r","?","r","r","?"),
           check.names = FALSE
           )

mappingList <- list("number 3",
                    "genres",
                    "music",
                    "number 12",
                    "music",
                    "fabric",
                    "colors")
```

In `DF` when a column that ends with suffix `former` and contains value "?", it needs to be encoded from the columns that ends with `latter`. By encoding I mean, `?` value in `former` column needs to be filled with whatever value there is in its corresponding `latter` column.  There can be multiple `latter` columns for a `former` column. Corresponding `latter` column for a `former` column is found from `mappingList`. For example for `colors number 3 former` there are 2 column indicators in `mappingList`: `genres` and `music` because they are under `number 3` which `colors number 3 former` belongs to and contains substring `number 3`. Within a for loop `colors number 3 former` should be encoded from `genres number 3 latter` first, for the rows that have the value `?`. If there are still `?` left in the `former` column the second option should be used for mapping, which is "music number 3 latter`(the next element under genres in number 3). The loop should stop if there are no more` ?`left in the`former`column, if not it should move down in the`mappingList` for that number. The original dataframe is much bigger, so manually mapping is not preferred. The expected output is:

```r
expectedDF <- data.frame(
           "colors number 3 former" = c("r","r","r","l","r","r","l","l","r","r"),
           "music number 3 latter" = c("r","l","r","l","r","r","l","l","r","l"),
           "genres number 3 latter" = c("l","r","?","l","?","r","?","l","l","r"),
           "genres number 12 former" = c("r","r","?","l","l","r","l","l","r","r"),
           "music number 12 latter" =  c("r","l","?","l","?","r","l","l","r","?"),
           "fabric number 12 latter" = c("l","r","?","l","r","r","r","l","l","r"),
           "colors number 12 latter" = c("r","r","?","r","?","r","?","r","r","?"),
           check.names = FALSE
           )
```

I tried out such an approach with nested loops but I cannot find a way to stop the loop once it reaches to the next number:

```r
# Take columns with that end with "former"
# Populate former columns in columnsToBeEncoded
columnsToBeEncoded <- list()
for(col in names(DF)){
  if(grepl("former", col)){
    columnsToBeEncoded <- append(columnsToBeEncoded, col)
  }
}

#columnsToBeEncoded

# Encode  "former" columns where row is "?" from "latter" columns by the order in mappingList
for(col in columnsToBeEncoded){
  # extract column number from former column
  colNumber <- paste(strsplit(col, " ")[[1]][2:3], collapse = " ")
  # Find indices where former column has "?"
  j <- which(DF[, col] == "?")
  for(element in mappingList){
    # I think the if statement below is not working
    # Inside the if statement I see elements with "number" in it are involved too
    if(!grepl(colNumber, element)){
      elementNameinColumnForm <- paste(c(element, colNumber, "latter"), collapse = " ")
      print(elementNameinColumnForm)
      DF[j,col] <- DF[j,elementNameinColumnForm]

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try if the following code works. It worked with the example you provided, so hopefully it works for more examples too:

```
columnsToBeEncoded = names(DF)[grepl("former", names(DF))] # alternative, vectorised form

# Create a nested list, where each key is a "number XX" and its elements are the variables needed
number_smth = which(grepl("number", mappingList))
mappingListNested = lapply(seq_along(number_smth), function(i){
  if (i+1 <= length(number_smth)){
    return(mappingList[(number_smth[i]+1):(number_smth[i+1]-1)])
  } else {
    return(mappingList[(number_smth[i]+1):length(mappingList)])
  }
})

names(mappingListNested) = paste('number', str_extract(mappingList[number_smth], "[[:digit:]]+"))

# Encode  "former" columns where row is "?" from "latter" columns by the order in mappingList
for(col in columnsToBeEncoded){
  # extract column number from former column
  colNumber <- paste(strsplit(col, " ")[[1]][2:3], collapse = " ")
  # Find indices where former column has "?"
  replacementVariables = mappingListNested[[colNumber]]
  for (var in replacementVariables){
    varNameinColumnForm <- paste(c(var, colNumber, "latter"), collapse = " ")
    DF[, col] = ifelse(
      DF[, col] == "?", # which elements are "?"
      DF[, varNameinColumnForm], # replace those which are "?" with the values of var
      DF[, col] # otherwise leave unchanged
    )
  }
}
```

Step by step:

1. I turned mappingList into a nested list to make the iterations easier. The nested list will have as many elements as "number XX" items in mappingList. Each element will be a character vector with the variables between that "number XX" and the next "number XX", which should be the replacement scheme if I understood you correctly.

```
number_smth = which(grepl("number", mappingList))
mappingListNested = lapply(seq_along(number_smth), function(i){
  if (i+1 <= length(number_smth)){
    return(mappingList[(number_smth[i]+1):(number_smth[i+1]-1)])
  } else {
    return(mappingList[(number_smth[i]+1):length(mappingList)])
  }
})
```

2. Name the list with the corresponding column names to make indexing easier. For that I extract the number inside each "number" in a similar manner as you do, only that I use regular expressions here (for which you will need the `stringr` package). You can actually leave it your way with `strsplit()` if you prefer

```
names(mappingListNested) = paste('number', stringr::str_extract(mappingList[number_smth], "[[:digit:]]+"))
```

3. The for loop scheme looks almost identical to yours, only that I use `ifelse()` to replace the values directly. `ifelse()` is a vectorised way of iterating through a vector, checking some condition and replacing the values that fulfill that condition with other values. The syntax is `ifelse(logical_vector, replacement_TRUE, replacement_FALSE)`.

   1. In my case, `logical_vector` is `DF[, col] == "?"`, which checks every element of the column `col` of DF if it is equal to "?". This will give a vector of `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s.
   2. The next argument is used to replace those elements of `DF[,col]` which are `TRUE` (i.e., the elements with "?"), which in this case is whatever variable there is in mappingListNested.
   3. The next argument (in this case, the column `DF[,col]` itself) will replace the elements that are `FALSE`, in other words it will leave the column unchanged wherever it is not "?"

```
# Encode  "former" columns where row is "?" from "latter" columns by the order in mappingList
for(col in columnsToBeEncoded){
  # extract column number from former column
  colNumber <- paste(strsplit(col, " ")[[1]][2:3], collapse = " ")
  # Find indices where former column has "?"
  replacementVariables = mappingListNested[[colNumber]]
  for (var in replacementVariables){
    varNameinColumnForm <- paste(c(var, colNumber, "latter"), collapse = " ")
    DF[, col] = ifelse(
      DF[, col] == "?", # which elements are "?"
      DF[, varNameinColumnForm], # replace those which are "?" with the values of var
      DF[, col] # otherwise leave unchanged
    )
  }
}
```

Since I iterate over the elements of mappingListNested, I make sure that the iterations will stop when the variables are over. Also, since the column `DF[,col]` is changed in place every iteration, that makes sure to replace first with the first variable, then with the next one, etc.

Comment: Also, as a general tip (and I hope not to sound condescendent with this), try to vectorise your R code, it will run faster. For loops are fine, but try avoiding ```append()```, it will slow your code down __a lot__. Instread, you can define an empty vector, re-define the values that you want, and then filter the "empty" spots out with a logical vector. I had once a script full of `append`s that used to take 6 hours to run, and doing what I just described cut the time to just 3 minutes (!). Just to show you how slow it can get with append, rbind, et. al

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution. Please refer to the comments in the code for exposition.

```
#----

#Your data.

DF <- data.frame(
  "colors number 3 former" = c("r","r","?","l","?","r","?","?","r","?"),
  "music number 3 latter" = c("r","l","r","l","r","r","l","l","r","l"),
  "genres number 3 latter" = c("l","r","?","l","?","r","?","l","l","r"),
  "genres number 12 former" = c("r","r","?","l","l","r","l","?","r","?"),
  "music number 12 latter" = c("r","l","?","l","?","r","l","l","r","?"),
  "fabric number 12 latter" = c("l","r","?","l","r","r","r","l","l","r"),
  "colors number 12 latter" = c("r","r","?","r","?","r","?","r","r","?"),
  check.names = FALSE
)

mappingList <- list("number 3",
                    "genres",
                    "music",
                    "number 12",
                    "music",
                    "fabric",
                    "colors")


expectedDF <- data.frame(
  "colors number 3 former" = c("r","r","r","l","r","r","l","l","r","r"),
  "music number 3 latter" = c("r","l","r","l","r","r","l","l","r","l"),
  "genres number 3 latter" = c("l","r","?","l","?","r","?","l","l","r"),
  "genres number 12 former" = c("r","r","?","l","l","r","l","l","r","r"),
  "music number 12 latter" =  c("r","l","?","l","?","r","l","l","r","?"),
  "fabric number 12 latter" = c("l","r","?","l","r","r","r","l","l","r"),
  "colors number 12 latter" = c("r","r","?","r","?","r","?","r","r","?"),
  check.names = FALSE
)


#--------

#Solution.

library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

#The mappingList isn't handy.
#Converting this into a data.frame with two columns: 
#"former", which indicates the former column in DF, 
#and "latter", which indicates the corresponding latter 
#column in DF from which the data in the former column 
#needs to be filled in.

mlist <- data.frame(latter = unlist(mappingList), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#A loop to identify former and latter values from the 
#data.frame's one available column.
j <- 0
for(i in 1:nrow(mlist)){
  if(str_detect(mlist$latter[i], "number [0-9]+")){
    j <- j + 1
  }
  mlist$type[i] <- j
}
rm(j)


#Munging to create the former and latter columns 
#properly.
mlist %<>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  mutate(former = latter[1]) %>% 
  ungroup()

mlist %<>% filter(latter != former)

mlist %<>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  mutate(ord = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup()

mlist %<>% select(c(former, latter, ord))

#For ease of use, bringing the former and latter 
#columns contents as close to the column names in 
#DF as is possible.
mlist %<>% 
  mutate(latter = paste0(latter, " ", former, " latter"), 
         former = paste0(former, " former"))


#Nested loops to fill in the DF rows.
#Basic logic is: take a row in DF.
#Loop through the rows of mlist.
#mlist basically holds the fill-in relationship's 
#column names. So extract the former and latter 
#(fcol and lcol) column names respectively.
#Then check if that particular former column in the 
#ith row of DF is a "?". If it is, fill it in with 
#the value from the cell corresponding to the column 
#name indicated by the jth row of mlist and the ith row 
#of DF.
#This also automatically takes care of the fact that the 
#next latter column's value gets used if a "?" remains.

for(i in 1:nrow(DF)){
  
  for(j in 1:nrow(mlist)){
    
    fcol <- colnames(DF)[str_detect(colnames(DF), mlist$former[j])]
    lcol <- colnames(DF)[str_detect(colnames(DF), mlist$latter[j])]
    
    if(DF[i, fcol] == "?"){
      DF[i, fcol] <- DF[i, lcol]
    }
    
  }
  
}


identical(DF, expectedDF)

# [1] TRUE

#----
```